# How to specify response using recipe package in Tidymodels

Tags: r, recipe, tidymodels

I am creating a recipe so that I first create a calculated column called "response" as so:

```
rec <- recipe( ~., data = training) %>%
  step_mutate(response = as.integer(all(c('A', 'B') %in% Col4) & Col4 == 'A'))
```

I would like to now specify this new calculated column as the response variable in the recipe() function as shown below. I will be doing a series of operations on it such as this first one with step_naomit. How do I re-specify my response in recipe() to be the calculated column from my previous step (above) using recipes?

```
recipe <- recipe(response ~ ., data = training) %>%
          step_naomit(recipe, response)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the role for new columns in the `step_mutate()` function by explictly setting the `role=` parmaeter.

```
rec <- recipe( ~., data = iris) %>%
  step_mutate(SepalSquared= Sepal.Length ^ 2, role="outcome")
```

Then check that it worked with `summary(prep(rec))`

```
  variable     type    role      source  
  <chr>        <chr>   <chr>     <chr>   
1 Sepal.Length numeric predictor original
2 Sepal.Width  numeric predictor original
3 Petal.Length numeric predictor original
4 Petal.Width  numeric predictor original
5 Species      nominal predictor original
6 SepalSquared numeric outcome   derived
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be perfect for what I'm trying to do, however, I'm running into an error that says ```Error: Cant subset columns that don't exist.``` Any idea on how to make my mutated column recognized in this case?

Comment: @ava It's tough to verify things work when you don't provide a reproducible example. I tried a different method and switched to the built in `iris` dataset to check that it worked.

Comment: Assigning the role within step_mutate instead seemed to do the trick! I appreciate the help and the sample with the Iris dataset. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is related to [tidymodel error, when calling predict function is asking for target variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67922740/tidymodel-error-when-calling-predict-function-is-asking-for-target-variable/67927214#67927214)

It is generally not advisable to modify the response inside your recipe. This is because the response variable won't be available to the recipe in certain cases, such as when using {tune}. I would recommend that you perform this transformation before you pass the data to the recipe. Even better if you do it before the validation split.

```
set.seed(1234)
data_split <-  my_data %>%
  step_mutate(response = as.integer(all(c('A', 'B') %in% Col4) & Col4 == 'A')) %>%
  initial_split()

training <- training(data_split)
testing <- testing(data_split)

rec <- recipe(response ~., data = training)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is good to know. If I did this outside of the recipe though, would I be able to save my final model with the following? ```final_model <- fit(workflow_object, dataset_total) saveRDS(final_model, "model.rds")``` I'd like to create this new field on newly introduced data as well.

Comment: The response will not be needed when you apply your fitted model to new data. Hence it doesn't matter if it is missing from the data you apply it to